# Determine which pairs of linearly ordered sets are order isomorphic

Tags: order-theory

Hi I've got an exam this Saturday and I don't understand this question at all. Could someone please explain it to me please? It would be much appreciated.

**Here is the question:** 
[image]

**and here is the answer:** 
[image]

Comment: It may seem like a lot of work, but it’d be quite helpful if you could transcribe the question and answer instead of just posting them as images. Doing so makes it easier for others to answer and for the knowledge on this site to be indexed.

Comment: Also, without any context or information about your current level of understanding, it’s difficult to know how to help you.

Comment: I don't know how to transcribe sorry. I'm sure it's easy to learn but I'm on a tight deadline and only have a short time to revise. I am taking an introductory module in set theory.

Comment: I fixed the images for you to make them in-site, but please [do not use image for the critical part](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/356647) of the question. Please edit and learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) and properly format math expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are given the lexicographical ordering $<_{\text{lex}}$, defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ as

$$(a,b) <_{\text{lex}} \iff a < c \text{ or ($a = c$ and $b < d$)}$$

where $<$ is just the usual ordering of real numbers.

This ordering is called *lexicographical* because it is a generalisation of the standard alphabetical ordering used in, for example, a dictionary. If we have two words and want to decide which one should come first, we look at the first letter and base our ordering on this. If both letters are the same, then we look at the second letter and use that to determine the ordering, and so on. In this case, we are just comparing two 2-tuples which you can imagine being two-letter words in our dictionary.

Now, we are being asked which pairs of the given linearly ordered sets are order isomorphic.

*Order isomorphic* means that there exists an *order isomorphism* between the two sets. An order isomorphism between two partially ordered sets, $(P, <_{P})$ and $(Q, <_{Q})$, is formally defined as a bijective function $f: P \to Q$ such that $\forall x, y \in P, x <_{P} y \iff f(x) <_{Q} f(y)$. Informally, this means that the two sets can be put into correspondence such that any two elements that are in a certain order in $P$ retain this order in $Q$. Of course, the elements in each set may not be the same, but the point is that by simply renaming them we can make the two sets virtually identical.

Let’s consider the first two sets.

$$(\mathbb{N}, <)\text{ and }(\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}, <_{\text{lex}})$$

The question is, can we construct a bijection between these sets so that our ordering is preserved?

Define $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ such that $
x \mapsto \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            \{\frac{n}{2}, 0\}, & x \text{ even} \\
            \{\frac{n-1}{2}, 1\}, & x \text{ odd}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$

It is relatively easy to verify that this is indeed a bijection.

$$0 \to \{0, 0\}$$
$$1 \to \{0, 1\}$$
$$2 \to \{1, 0\}$$
$$3 \to \{1, 1\}$$
$$4 \to \{2, 0\}$$ $$\vdots$$

and so every pair in $\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}$ will be covered exactly once (no need to formally prove it here).

Now we can quickly consider whether our other condition is met. Namely, we require $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{N}, x < y \iff f(x) <_{\text{lex}} f(y)$.

If x and y are both even, we want $x < y \iff \{\frac{x}{2}, 0\} <_{\text{lex}} \{\frac{y}{2}, 0\}$, which is true.

If $x$ and $y$ are both odd, we have a similar situation.

If $x$ is even and $y$ is odd, we want $x < y \iff \{\frac{x}{2}, 0\} < \{\frac{y-1}{2}, 1\}$. In this case, it is clearly true if $x$ and $y$ are far apart. However, consider when $y = x + 1$. Then the first element of these two sets are equal. But, according to our lexicographical ordering, we look at the second element and decide that $f(x) <_{\text{lex}}
 f(y)$, so the order is preserved.

The case where $x$ is odd and $y$ is even is similar.

Since we have an order isomorphism between the two sets, we say they are order isomorphic.

Now, consider the second pair.

$$(\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}, <_{\text{lex}}) \text{ and } (\{0,1\} \times \mathbb{N}, <_{\text{lex}})$$

Can we construct a bijection here? Well, if we map each pair in the first set to its ‘swapped version’ in the second, defining $f: \mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\} \to \{0,1\} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{x,y\} \mapsto \{y,x\}$, then this is a bijection. However, when we check if order is preserved, things break down. For example, it is indeed true that $\{2, 0\} <_{\text{lex}} \{3, 0\}$ and $\{0, 2\} <_{\text{lex}} \{0, 3\}$, but if we consider a slightly different pair we have $\{2,1\} <_{\text{lex}} \{3,0\}$ but $\{1,2\} \not <_{\text{lex}} \{0,3\}$. Maybe we could find another bijection that does meet the extra condition required to be order isomorphism, but it doesn't seem obvious. Indeed, according to the answers, the two sets are not order isomorphic.

Hopefully you should be able to consider the other sets and apply similar logic to reach a conclusion. As the question states, you do not have to justify your answers, so using intuition is especially useful here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very informative answer. I don't quite get why (ℕ,<) isn't order isomorphic to ({0,1}×ℕ,<lex) though. I've also had a go at iii and iv but I'm not sure if I'm right. My understanding was that you can't construct a bijection between any of the sets be it with Q or R but for iii there is one order isomorphic pair and I don't get why. Would you mind explaining?

Comment: Consider $(\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\})$ again. This set, when ordered using $<_{\text{lex}}$, looks like two pairs ‘for each’ natural number: $\{1,0\},\{1,1\},\{2,0\},\{2,1\},\{3,0\},\dots$. $(\{0,1\} \times \mathbb{N})$, though, looks more like a whole infinite string of pairs, one for each natural number, and *then* another infinite string of pairs: $\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{0,3\},\dots,\{1,1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\dots$ It seems like these two sets have a fundamentally different structure.

Comment: For example, some elements in the latter set are greater than an infinite number of other elements whilst also being less than an infinite number of elements. Does $\mathbb{N}$ have elements like this?

Comment: If you’re confused as to how there can be such a difference between two sets that are simply ‘reflections’ of each other, remember that the ordering we are given is in a certain sense asymmetric. It treats the two elements of the set totally differently.

Comment: In your first comment why is it that for (ℕ×{0,1}) you have {1,0},{1,1},{2,0},{2,1},{3,0},... and not {0,1},{0,2},{0,3},…,{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},...?

Comment: $\times$ here denotes the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

Comment: Ah thank you very rusty at the moment.

Comment: About the second situation you considered, it is easier to see that $\{0,1\}\times\mathbb N$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb N$. In a intuitive way, if you consider the Hasse diagrams of the posets, the first consists of two copies of $\mathbb N$, one on top of the other. This type of reasoning should also be helpful in the other cases.

Comment: @amrsa Yes, that’s very helpful indeed.